# How can I monitor a folder with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, directory

I want to create a Cocoa application to monitor a folder for new files on Mac OS X. I know I can do this using AppleScript and Folder Actions, but how can I use ObjC and Cocoa for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at [File System Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Although, for really fine-grained monitoring the documentation points to using [kqueues](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html)

Comment: To that end, check out UKKQueue - nice easy wrapper. http://zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm

Comment: I've worked with File System Events quite a bit and it drops a lot of events, so for watching a single folder I'd go with kqueue.  Note that a kqueue will not alert you if a file in your watched folder is replaced with a new file of the same name (because the folder attributes won't change). You'll want to add existing files to the queue along with the folder path if you need this functionality.

Comment: **Important:** This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information about Apple SDKs, visit the [documentation website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation).